# React Router will not take array as prop for a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am trying to pass an array of objects as a prop to a new route. However, whenever I pass the prop and go to that route on my browser, I can see (using console.log) that the array in the prop exists, but it is empty. I'm not sure how to fix this. I've verified that the array is populated before it is passed as a prop.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            routes: []
        }
    }

    addToRoute(record){
        let tempRoutes = this.state.routes.slice();
        tempRoutes[record.id] = record;
        this.setState({
            routes: tempRoutes
        })
    }    

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Subapp addToRoute={(record) => this.addToRoute(record)}/>}/>
                <Route path={"/record/:id"} render={({match})=><BasicInfo  match={match} {...this.state}/>}/>
            </div>
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: use redux state

Comment: can you say what is match in second route?

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala this is basic react-router stuff https://react-router.now.sh/

Comment: where is the console log that shows the wrong values? show the BasicInfo component?

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure where in your app things go wrong, but I do see a few obvious parts in your code that tripped my app up when I was trying to re-create your problem.

```
<Route exact path='/' render={() => <Subapp addToRoute={(record) => this.addToRoute(record)}/>}/>
```

Here just pass in `this.addToRoute` You populate the param within the component.

```
<Route path={"/record/:id"} render={({match})=><BasicInfo  match={match} {...this.state}/>}/>
```

Restrain yourself from passing on the entire state when possible. Instead, try to explicitly define the props you need. If you don't you might extend state in your component in the future. Then, those new parts of the state are passed along too. Also, explicitly defining props will make your code more readable.

```
this.state = {
    routes: []
}

addToRoute(record){
    let tempRoutes = this.state.routes.slice();
    tempRoutes[record.id] = record;
    this.setState({
        routes: tempRoutes
    })
}
```

This won't work. `state` is an array initially, while in `addToRoute()` you transform it into an object.

So, you do have some inconsistencies within your code. In trying to recreate your problem I was unable to make the code work because of these errors. After making some adjustments it runs. As you can see I'm passing down the routes object and it is populated in `<BasicInfo />`. Have a look at [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m4w4r0ml99) for a working example.

Let me know if that answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it did not seem to fix the problem. It seems like React Router is taking in my initial routes, but it never updates when addToRoute is called. Making it always an empty array(or object depending on implementation). Any ideas on how to fix this?